# Carregar imagem aleatória no background-image usando css

Tags: css

É possível **usando apenas css**, fazer o carregamento de imagens aleatórias na propriedade background-image de um elemento qualquer?

Por exemplo tenho uma section

```
<section id="slide">

</section>
```

E tenho uma pasta chamada img que contém 5 arquivos

```
background-1-img.png
background-2-img.png
background-3-img.png
background-4-img.png
background-5-img.png
```

Toda vez que fosse carregada a página que contém essa section, uma das imagens desse diretório deveria ser setada na propriedade background-image da section de maneira **aleatória**.

A minha dúvida é, posso fazer isso só com CSS, ou precisarei do JavaScript para isso?

Comment: Acredito que apenas em css essa aleatoriedade não será possível, você tem o conhecimento para resolver isso em js ou outra linguagem de sua preferência?

Comment: Sim, em js tenho, mas queria saber se dava para fazer em css

Comment: O mais perto de conseguires aquilo que queres é usando animação. Não é aleatória, mas permite que as imagens vão mudando. Se quiseres um exemplo para trabalhares é só contactares comigo. Se quiseres a parte aleatória tens de utilizar sempre JS.

Comment: Tenho quase certeza que que só com **CSS** isso não é possível, talvez com **PHP**, fazendo uma consulta aleatória no banco de dados (MySQL). A consulta ficaria mais ou menos assim: "SELECT * FROM banners ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1", Com isso tu salva numa variável.